How to deploy microfrontend service on aws ecs fargate which is running main frontend , we have 1 ALB with multiple target groups
We have main frontend service with multiple backend services , deployed on ECS fargate using ALB and multiple target groups
Main frontend has nginx config and is served at /
Now microfrontend service will be deployed as a new service container on ecs fargate under same ALB with /mfe as its forwarding path on ALB
so what shall be its nginx config individually on its task/service running on fargate
**ecs task for main frotend has been serving on Domain-name/ **
    server {
  #listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name localhost;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.pem;
  ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
  gzip                    on;
  gzip_comp_level         3;
  gzip_vary               on;
  gzip_min_length         1000;
  gzip_proxied            any;
  gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_buffers            16 8k;
  client_max_body_size    256M;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/mainfrontend;

  index index.html;

  location /health {
        access_log off;
        return 200;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;  
  }                                         

}

**for microfrontend we want it should be served as Domain-name/mfe ** what will be nginx config for this so that it can accessed via main frontend and on browser as /mfe whereas we dont have any folder named "mfe"- nor we want this dependency
